# Ubuntu 22.04 Server BTRFS root

Tags: server, partitioning, 22.04, btrfs

I am trying to install ubuntu server 22.04 on a BTRFS root partition but i cannot get past the installer not allowing me to set the root filesystem on a btrfs partition.

My Disk layout:

- 3 500GB SSDs (2 connected to NVME and one SATA)
- 2 2TB HDDS (connected to SATA)

What I want:

- RAID0 on BTRFS for my root and boot partitions (over all three ssds)
- RAID1 on the HDDS (can be done later, will not be part of the basic filesystem layout)

What I have done so far:

1. Created an EFI partition on one of the SSDS
2. Partitioned all other disks with one BTRFS partition
3. Created a raid0 BTRFS volume: `mkfs.btrfs --d raid0 /dev/x /dev/y /dev/z` (exiting the installer)
4. used `btrfs devices scan`
5. Returned to the installer (with CTRL+ALT+F2)

Still cannot select / for installation, it is grayed out.

When setting / manually to one of the BTRFS partitions the installer crashes after trying to install the bootloader.

Comment: You should avoid creating a RAID array on drives on different interfaces, as there will be issues with performance (SATA is much slower than NVME).   
You could create a RAID0 array with the 2 NVME drives.  
Please share the installer logs, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong, I could not use preformatted BTRFS partitions. They should be formatted again during the installation process, after selecting the format option, I could also select `\` as the destination mount point.